# Spring Web REST call special characters encoding

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am having troubles transferring strings, containing special characters from one java service to another java service. Here's what's happening. On the 'client' im having a following call:

```
final String url = baseUrl() + "/getOrders";
final UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url);
builder.queryParam("username", username);

final ResponseEntity<TResponse> restResp = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, OrdersResult.class);
```

On a 'server' side there is a method with a following signature:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getOrders", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public OrdersResult getOrders(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username)
```

The problem is that if username contains any special character, like '+' or '|', username string gets to server with a white spaces instead of an actual character. For instance:

> "I+Am|A+User" -> "I Am A User"

I can fix it by manually encode url parameter on client:

```
builder.queryParam("username", URLEncoder.encode(username, 'UTF-8'));
```

and then decode on server.

Is there any way to avoid manual encoding/decoding?

Answer (score 1):

On a browser side query params are usually encoded with `encodeUriComponent`. So, the special characters can be transferred correctly. Then the server application decodes the string to original value.

Therefore, I see no problems with the approach you proposed.

Comment: Yes, exactly. There is an encodeUriComponent on our Angular side.